# Plaid - PAYMENT_STATUS_INPUT_NEEDED

Tags: javascript, plaid

I've got Plaid payment initiation working on my cart but for some reason, all payments have the status of "PAYMENT_STATUS_INPUT_NEEDED".

Also, I can only get Plaid to work if "receivedRedirectUri" is omitted when making the "plaid.Create" call. If I include it, Plaid throws the following error:

```
display_message: null
documentation_url: "https://plaid.com/docs/?ref=error#invalid-request-errors"
error_code: "INVALID_FIELD"
error_message: "oauth_continuation.link_token does not match session"
error_type: "INVALID_REQUEST"
request_id: "aseWi7KyiQwxuVE"
suggested_action: null
```

Has anyone come across this? Plaid's docs don't seem to cover this. This is what my function looks like.

```
async plaidPay() {
    let amount = this.cart[0].item.amount * this.cart[0].quantity;
    console.log(window.location.href);
    
    const linkToken = await this.$axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'api/plaid-create-payment',
    data: { amount: amount },
    config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }}
    })
    .then(res => {
        return res.data.link_token;
        
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
    })

    console.log(linkToken);

    const handler = window.Plaid.create({
        token: linkToken,
        onSuccess: (public_token, metadata) => {
            console.log('test 1');
            console.log(public_token);
            console.log(metadata);
        },
        onLoad: () => {
            console.log('test 2');
        },
        onExit: (err, metadata) => {
            console.log('test 3');
            console.log(err);
            console.log(metadata);
        },
        onEvent: (eventName, metadata) => {
            console.log('test 4');
            console.log(eventName);
            console.log(metadata);
        },
        //required for OAuth; if not using OAuth, set to null or omit:
        receivedRedirectUri: window.location.href,
    });

    handler.open();   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question is being handled by Plaid support, but for posterity and the benefit of those Googling, the issue seems to be that you are launching with `receivedRedirectUri` the first time you launch Link. This field should only be included when reinitializating Link, after returning from the OAuth flow.